# What is a good way to visualize a large as3 project?

Tags: actionscript-3, visualization

I've build a fairly large system in as3 and now I need to introduce some other programmers in the different parts, and hopfully they will eventually grasp the entire system.

I need to describe relations between classes and maybe some kind of flow, but the relations are the most important.

I've checked UML but I find it a bit strict and would like to be able to write comments about specific classes or relations and maybe be able to draw curved lines/arrows etc. In UML I also find it hard to know which kind of lines/arrows to use when and where.

So I am looking for a method/software/tutorial on this topic, either on some extended/simplified UML or a completely different method.

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [Crocus Modeller UML for AS3 & Flex](http://crocusmodeller.com). You can import your code and create  cute diagram (explaining it to other people is then a joy). Also, there are some tips reminding you very quickly UML relations.

Comment: Very nice, would be incredible if it also could generate documentation! And also it cannot export my project as an image since it is too big :( But nice tool!!